# Create an upload controller action for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, rails-routing

I'm making a Rails app, and want to add an upload feature with allows users to upload multiple entries at once through an Excel spreadsheet as opposed to entering one entry at a time.

Ideally, I was hoping to add a separate Upload/Submit portion to the bottom of the new.html.erb file (the bold portion being the Upload HTML.erb):

```
...
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>

**<div class="field">
    Or Upload Multiple Entries <br />        
    <%= form_tag({:action => :upload}, :multipart => true) do %>
        <%= file_field_tag 'multi_doc' %>        
    <% end %>
</div>**
```

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
Dataway::Application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users

    resources :revenue_models do
      get 'upload', :on => :collection         
    end

    root :to => "home#index"
end
```

And my revenue_models_controller (haven't developed the action at all yet, now just a redirect):

```
...
def upload
    redirect_to revenue_models_path
end
```

I have followed the rails guides for [Uploading files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files) as well as for [Routing files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) and I keep getting an error when I attempt to open the /new view I have modified:

```
    Routing Error
        No route matches {:action=>"upload", :controller=>"revenue_models"}
    Try running rake routes
```

When I run rake route, I get an entry for the upload action:

```
upload_revenue_models GET    /revenue_models/upload(.:format)   revenue_models#upload
```

In the end, what I would like to do is upload an excel file with multiple entries, parse it, and conditionally add each data row to my database, which I was under the impression I could specify in the upload action. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Please use `form_for` instead `form_tag`.

Second What is `multi_doc` is a `field/attribute` of `revenue_model`?. I guess is a `field/attribute` of `revenue_model`.

Third, Where is your instance variable `revenue_model` in the form?

Fourth, You have to create first a instance variable of your Model, on your action/controller where you are showing the form, for example `@revenue_model = RevenueModel.new`.

After try this code:

```
<%= form_for(@revenue_model, :method => :get, :html => {:multipart => true}, :url => { :controller => "revenue_models", :action => "upload"})) do |f| %>
 <%= f.file_field :multi_doc %>
 <%= f.submit :id => "any_id" %>
<% end %>
```

The question is very confusing, trying to clarify your question specifying the name of your actions and the names of the files in your views.

Regards!

Comment: so I don't have a field for this file upload in my model, I am confused on how to pass the uploaded file from the view to the controller to then modify. Creating an instance of my revenue_model doesn't make sense to me as I am not passing any attributes to my revenue_model DB without extracting/parsing the multiple entries from the uploaded Excel doc first. Sorry for the confusion, I hope that helps, thanks for your help.